# How to find out what the source of an NS Log is?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nslog

I've been attaching sound files to my app in different if else statements on the push of a button. For some reason, one of the sounds always plays (thank you) once the button is pressed and i cant find the source. Sometimes, it overlaps with existing sounds.
Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    weather.enabled=NO;
    weather.hidden=YES;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)go:(id)sender {
        NSString *string =text.text;
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"friend"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"You're my best friend";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"You're my best friend" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");


       }
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"hat are you doing"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"I'm talking to you";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"I'm talking to you" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");
}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"favorite snack"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Ooooh. I love chips.";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chips" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");


}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"was your day"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"It was techy";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"it was techy" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");

        }
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"weather"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Cloudy with a chance of meatballs, GET It? But really, click below";
        weather.enabled=YES;
        weather.hidden=NO;
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Weather" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");
}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"the time"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"I'm not sure. There must be a clock somewhere near.";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"time" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");
}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"your birthday"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"I was born one day in an Apple Computer. I can't seem to remember when that was.";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Your birthday" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");
}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"ello"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Hi";  SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hi" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");
}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"yes"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Ok"; SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ok" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");
}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"sure"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Ok"; SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ok" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");
}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"yeah"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Ok";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ok" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"do you do"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"I am a student";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"im a student" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"awesome"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Thank You";SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Thanks" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"hi"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Hi"; SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hi" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");
}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"favorite color"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"My favorite color is Orange";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my favorite color" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"Hi"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Hello";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hi" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"sup"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Nothing much";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nothing much" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"how are you"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"I'm fine. Thank You";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"im fine" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"How are you"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"I'm fine. Thank You";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"im fine" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"Cool"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Thanks";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"thanks informal" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"cool"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Thanks";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"thanks informal" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"should I call you"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"You can call me Cara";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"you can call me cara" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"nice name"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Thanks";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"thanks informal" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"you born"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"I was born in an Apple Computer";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"born in apple" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"language"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"I speak english";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ispeakenglish" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"nice name"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Thanks";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"thanks informal" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"ok"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Great";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"grt" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"old are you"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"That's a little personal. Can we please talk about something else?";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"thatspersonal" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"free time"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else{label.text = @"I like to sleep.";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"liketosleep" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"nice name"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Thanks";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"thanks informal" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"name"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"My name is Cara";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"you can call me cara" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");

    }

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"thank"].location == NSNotFound) {


    }
    else {label.text = @"You're very welcome";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"welcome" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"thank"].location == NSNotFound) {


    }
    else {label.text = @"You're very welcome";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"welcome" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}


    if ([string rangeOfString:@"thank"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"You're very welcome";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"welcome" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"you live"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"I live right here on your device";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"live" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"love you"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"You're so nice";}
    SystemSoundID SoundID;
    NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Thanks" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
    NSLog(@"sound played");

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"amazing"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Thank you";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"thanks" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"hate"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"I'm sorry. I do my best";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imsorry" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"homework"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Well, I don't think I'm smart enough. But you are!!";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"smarthw" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");
    }
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"you like school"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Umm, sometimes";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sometimes" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"have any siblings"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"No. I'm an only child.";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"onlychild" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@" you have friends"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Yes. You're my best friend";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"You're my best friend" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");

}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"be my friend"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Sure";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sure 3.31.32 PM " ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"Good morning"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Good morning";
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"morning" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"Good night"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Good Night";}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"Good Night"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Good Night";}

if ([string rangeOfString:@"Good Morning"].location == NSNotFound) {

}
else {label.text = @"Good morning";}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"Good morning"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Good morning";}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"favorite tv show"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"I love the Simpsons. It's so funny. Have you heard about it?";}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"favorite TV show"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"I love the Simpsons. It's so funny. Have you heard of it?";}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"favorite sport"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"My favorite sport is soccer. What's your favorite sport?";}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"baseball"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Nice";}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"basketball"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Nice";}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"soccer"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Cool";}
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"swimming"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"Cool";}


    if ([string rangeOfString:@"football"].location == NSNotFound) {
    }
    else {label.text = @"Cool";}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"favorite food"].location == NSNotFound) {
    }
    else {label.text = @"Chips. Get it?";}


    if ([string rangeOfString:@"No"].location == NSNotFound) {
    }
    else {label.text = @"Oh";}


    if ([string rangeOfString:@"music do you like"].location == NSNotFound) {
    }
    else {label.text = @"I like to listen to the band Imagine Dragons";}



    if ([string rangeOfString:@"What's up"].location == NSNotFound) {
    }
    else {label.text = @"The Sky. GET IT?. I'm just messing.";}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"What's up"].location == NSNotFound) {
    }
    else {label.text = @"The Sky. GET IT?. I'm just messing.";}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"what's up"].location == NSNotFound) {
    }
    else {label.text = @"The Sky. GET IT?. I'm just messing.";}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"favorite sport"].location == NSNotFound) {
    }
    else {label.text = @"I love soccer. What sport do you like?";}

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"favorite song"].location == NSNotFound) {

    }
    else {label.text = @"I love to listen to Chimes by Hudson Mohawke.";}
}

- (IBAction)weather:(id)sender {
    weather.enabled=NO;
    weather.hidden=YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.weather.com/weather/today/l/USNJ0413:1:US"]];
}
```

Comment: Use breakpoints and the debugger or be sure to use unique messages in each `NSLog` statement. Example: `NSLog(@"sound played 1");`, `NSLog(@"sound played 2");`,

Comment: More to the point, you clearly would have benefitted from creating a method where you pass in a string that is a sound file name, and the method plays that sound. Then you would have only 1 "sound played" NSLog, you'd set a break point on it, and you'd go up the stack to see where it was called from!

Comment: Since you made the bed, you have to lie in it. Set breakpoints on ALL the NSLogs if you must. But really, fix your code to remove all the repetition!! And as long as we're talking about code reduction, if you had a dictionary that mapped label.text strings to sound file names, you could replace all the if...else code with a single loop through the dictionary!

Comment: to be honest... im not too good at this so.. yeah if and else was the most basic thing

Comment: it would be helpful if u could be more specific about the dictionary

Comment: Any time you have the same code repeated over and over with only the values changing, it's a sign that there is a better way of doing it. This is a typical naive programmer's approach. It's also what's known in the business as a "code smell".

Comment: I went the extra mile and wrote you an example of how to use minimal code and just list in two dictionaries the various strings to check for, sound file names, and label text values you might want to display.

Comment: Fully agree with the other comments about rewriting the code. Note also that you can use 'Ctrl-I' to let XCode re-indent your code. Then you would have easily seen that you have incorrect braces placement under @"love you".

Comment: It's not "code smell" -- As Maynard G. Krebs would say, it's "Work?!", and that's always to be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @fishinear - No need to remember 'Ctrl-I'.  Just highlight the section, RMB, select (IIRC) "Format", then "Indent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code using a cleaner approach:

```
// not all values present, just a sample here
NSDictionary *stringsToSounds = @{@"friend":@"You're my best friend", @"hat are you doing":@"I'm talking to you", @"chips":@"chipds"};

NSDictionary *stringsToLabels = @{@"friend":@"You're my best friend", @"hat are you doing":@"I'm talking to you", @"chips":@"Ooooh. I love chips."};

for(NSString *s in stringsToSounds) {
    if([string rangeOfString:s] != NSNotFound) {
        if(stringsToLabels[s]) {
            [label setText:stringsToLabels[s]];
        }
        [self playSound:stringsToSounds[s]];
        break;
    }
}
```

and method playSound looks like:

-

```
    (void) playSound(NSString *) soundFileName {
        SystemSoundID SoundID;
        NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundFileName ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
        NSLog(@"sound played");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster suggested, you could use a dictionary to look up the sound to play for different label values. The code might look like this:

```
-(void) playSoundForLabelText: (NSString *) text
{
  //Build a dictionary where each key is the string to search for, and the value is the name of the sound to play.
  NSDictionary *soundFileNames = @{@"I was born one day in an Apple Computer. I can't seem to remember when that was.": @"Your birthday",
  @"Ooooh. I love chips.": @"chips",
  @"Cloudy with a chance of meatballs, GET It? But really, click below": @"Weather"};

  //Attempt to fetch a sound file name for the key in "text"
  NSString *soundName = soundFileNames[text];
  if (soundName != nil)
  {
    NSString *soundfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: soundName ofType:@"mp3"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundfile], &SoundID );
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
    NSLog(@"Played sound %@", soundName);
  }
  else
    NSLog(@"No sound found for key %@", text);
}
```

Then you'd use that method with code like this:

```
NSString *labelText = label.text;
[self playSoundForLabelText: labelText];
```

This code isn't optimized. It creates the dictionary that maps label text to sound file names every time, which is inefficient, but it gives you the general idea.

BTW, AVAudioPlayer is usually a better choice for playing sounds than AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID. Do a search on AVAudioPlayer in the Xcode docs to learn more.